# Which "Standard arrows" (Wooden, Large etc) are the same "weight" as "Special arrows"?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls

In DkS1 and DkS2, there are several types of arrows you can use; both "plain" (wooden, large, etc) and "special" (like Poison, or Fire for example). However, if you compare the flight of a Standard Arrow to the flight of a Heavy Arrow, you will find they have different trajectories. I.e, a Heavy Arrow will not fly as far as a Standard Arrow, if you aim at the same point.

Now, my question is; **which "Standard arrow" variant has the same trajectory as a "Special arrow"?**

Note: I realize that this may be different between games, and that there are different versions in either game (e.g. DkS2 has "Special" Great Arrows, while DkS1 does not)

Comment: From experience, at least with bolts, special bolts are the same weight at as the heavy ones.... or at least that's what I recall happening, but I think this needs !!SCIENCE!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dark Souls 1 Answer - **Standard Arrows**.

This was tested in the invasion of Lautrec's World. I tested both the Poison and Fire Arrows, with comparison against Wooden, Standard, Feathered, and Large arrows.